# Bash conditional expression: `-o`. What does it mean?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I am trying to understand what dose the `-o` mean in the following `bash` `if` script.

looking at the results I can guess what it does but I do really need to get the concept of it.

```
i=1
for day in Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
do
 echo -n "Day $((i++)) : $day"
 if [ $i -eq 7 -o $i -eq 8 ]; then
   echo " (WEEKEND)"
   continue;
 fi
 echo " (weekday)"
done
```

The results are as following:

```
$ ./for7.sh
Day 1 : Mon (weekday)
Day 2 : Tue (weekday)
Day 3 : Wed (weekday)
Day 4 : Thu (weekday)
Day 5 : Fri (weekday)
Day 6 : Sat (WEEKEND)
Day 7 : Sun (WEEKEND)
```

Comment: As it is used there, it means `||` (OR). e.g. `$i -eq 7` OR `$i -eq 8`. It can also be used to test whether an option set by `set` is set... (that's a lot of sets). That is why you are better off using `[ "$i" -eq 7 ] || [ "$i" -eq 8 ]` (**note:** always *quote* your variables with `[...]`)

Comment: If you use bash then `[` is a builtin command. See: `help test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-o` symbolizes Logical OR here.

Do `man test` which explains this.

```
 EXPRESSION1 -o EXPRESSION2
              either EXPRESSION1 or EXPRESSION2 is true
```